# How to fix my scroll to top feature on my webpage

Tags: javascript, html

If you look here as an example:

https://help-msa.publictalksoftware.co.uk/

It is supposed to support a scroll to top feature and it has stopped working.

When you view the source you will see this in the `head` of every page:

```
  <!-- For "Scroll to top" -->
  <link id="msa-font-awesome-css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/fontawesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css?ver=4.7.0" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script defer src="js/fontawesome.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
  #myBtn {
    position: fixed;
    right: 40px;
    bottom: 65px;
    display: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: #d35438 !important;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 30px 30px -30px #7F7F7F, inset 0 -30px 30px -30px #7F7F7F;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 30px 30px -30px #7F7F7F, inset 0 -30px 30px -30px #7F7F7F;
    box-shadow: inset 0 30px 30px -30px #606060, inset 0 -30px 30px -30px #606060;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #E7D8A3 !important;
    padding: 8px;
    font-size: 20px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s linear 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s linear 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.1s linear 0s;
    transition: all 0.1s linear 0s;
    font-family: 'Tahoma', sans-serif;
    z-index: 99999999;
  }
  #myBtn:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #000000;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #000000;
  }  
  </style>
```

And towards the bottom I have this on every page:

```
  <!-- Code for scrolling back to the top of the article -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    <!-- When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button -->
    window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

    function scrollFunction() {
      if (document.body.scrollTop > 100 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100) {
        document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "block";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  
    $('#myBtn').on('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 1000);
    });
  </script>
```

When I examine the Google Chrome console it says:

[image: Console warnings]

I don't understand why this feature has stopped working. I am grateful for any guidance to resolve.

Comment: Does `#myBtn` exist at the point where the code runs? (Or at all)

Comment: You need to place div (or any other html element) with proper ID in proper place where you want to scroll.

Comment: Check if Scroll to Top button has Id "myBtn"

Comment: Is your example verbatim? `<!--COMMENT-->` applies to comments in HTML. This is not valid comment syntax for JavaScript or CSS. Any comments within a `<style>` element must be wrapped in forward slashes and asterisks `/*COMMENT*/`. Any comments within a `<script>` element must be wrapped like a CSS comment or prefixed with 2 forward slashes `//COMMENT`.

Comment: Got it. I had updated a template in a recent upgrade and forgot a line of code.

Comment: @zer00ne I will fix the comments syntax in the javascript code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the advise in the comments I was able to identify the issue.

I had recently upgraded HelpNDoc, which is the product I use to build the help documentation, and I had tried to upgrade the default HTML template.

I accidently forget to include two lines of code:

```
  <div id="main">
    <!-- Display button to scroll back to the top of the article -->
    <button id="myBtn" title="Scroll to top"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></button>
    <article>
```

I show the two lines "in context".

Thanks again guys.